# Dual boot & boot loop Linux-Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I will go directly to the subject. I have a homework for my university and our teacher wants to make a dual boot of linux and Windows (the easy part), but he want to create a boot loop so that when we are on grub and choose Linux, we login to linux. If we choose Windows, it will redirect us to Windows Boot Manager. From there, if we choose windows, we login to Windows, but if you choose linux it will redirect back to grub.

So we have:

**Grub:**

Linux > login to Linux

Windows > redirect to Windows Boot Manager

Windows Boot Manager:

Windows > login to Windows

Linux > redirect to grub

I'm not asking for the solution but for some information about what to check and where.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Normal grub will find Windows & add it automatically to grub boot menu if both systems are UEFI or both are BIOS boot. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen Windows does not boot other systems, if UEFI you can add Ubuntu entry, but if BIOS you probably need a third party tool like EasyBCD which uses grub4dos to chainload to grub2.

Comment: I don't care if it's bios or uefi But maybe you don't understand what I want exactly. Now I have a dual boot and it's working perfect. 
imagine that you have two hdd lets say A and B.

In disk A you have LInux and in disk B windows 

You start with disk A and in grub you have choice 1) log in in linux 2)go to Disk B and find windows boot manager

You are in disk B you see again two choices. 1) log in in windows 2)go to disk A and find grub

That is what i need to do

Comment: I won't answer your homework question for you but I suggest you look at modifying the Windows boot loader. I'm afraid you've asked an unanswerable question - we don't do homework so we can't answer but just give suggestions. So, check your options to modify your boot loader on the Windows drive. Google will show you the way.

Comment: @KGIII as you can see in my first post I wrote that i don't ask for a solution but some help about what to check etc :)

Thanks for the answer! I will check it as soon as I finished my other assignments.

Comment: @Stefos I caught that and that's why I mentioned that it is an unanswerable question as no correct answer can really be given without doing the work for  you. The hint *should* be enough. A final hint might be to make sure that any editing is done with a plain text editor and not something that adds markup like Wordpad or Word or some such. Enjoy - that *should* be enough but if it's not then let us know what you've tried and what you've had for successes.

Comment: It makes a huge difference if an older system using BIOS & MBR. Or a newer system using UEFI. I always kept Windows XP BIOS boot loader on a Windows drive as sda. Windows just prefers to be sda. And grub on sdb booting either Ubuntu or Windows. I did not try to boot grub from Windows as not required, but some do it with third party tools or dd copy of MBR or PBR to a file and adding that to Windows. Most with newer Windows then would use third party tools as easier to configure.

Comment: @Stefos EasyBCD will work. But, both Operating Systems must be on same Interface [BIOS or UEFI].

Comment: @Sagar yeah I know that. I have so many assignments for now that I have to postpone this one! I 'll try EasyBCD. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EasyBCD** is the solution

- **To Download EasyBCD** **[here](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)**.
- Press **`See Plans`**.
- Look for **`Non-commercial Plan`**.
- Press **`Register`** Button.
- Enter any **`Name and Email ID`**.
- Press **`Download!`**.
- [See Instructions For using EasyBCD](https://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-the-boot-menu-windows-8/)

Comment: @stefos https://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-the-boot-menu-windows-8/

Comment: Ok it was easier than I thought. It's almost working as i want. The only problem is that when I'm in grub and choose windows I get some error I have to press enter and then i think it restarts. (too tired and i don;'t remember exactly). If i'm right i have to configure something in grub from linux right?

Comment: Update to previous answer. I getting an "error"
setting partition type to 0x7

So I think i have to change something in grub. I will check it later this week but it works! Thanks for the answers

Comment: Update: I fixed the error i got by editing grub. I put "boot" at the end of Windows entry in grub (Used grub customizer). It's looks like
...
drivemap -s (hd0) $(root)
chainloader +1
boot

Thanks everyone who answered!